# GetMapping изменяет путь

Tags: java, spring-boot

Web приложение на Spring-Boot
На странице имеется ссылка

```html
<a th:href="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}">Edit</a>
```

Контроллер, который обрабатывает этот запрос:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/people/{id}")
public String showPeopleEdit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") long id) {
  People people = peopleService.get(id);
  model.addAttribute("people", people);
  return "people-edit";
}
```

Вот people-edit:

```html
<form id="02" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/people/edit/{id}(id=${people.getId()})}" th:object="${people}">
    <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <label for="inp">Номер</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inp" placeholder="Введите имя" th:field="*{name}" autofocus required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Страница people-edit открывается, но браузер не находит там css-файлы, т.к. он ищет их почему-то относительно пути:

/people/css/namefile.css

Конечно их там нет.
Что я делаю не так?
И еще вопрос: если мне нужно будет обработать несколько контроллеров с этой страницы и я напишу, например так:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/people/add/{id}")
```

то он ваще начинает css искать в /people/add

И почему тогда у меня есть ссылка на предыдущей странице:

```html
<a href="/show-people" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Show</a>
```

Контроллер к нему:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/show-people")
  public String showAllPeople() {
  return "show-people";
}
```

И там все нормально отрабатывает, находит все css-файлы

Вот код из шаблона загрузки стилей:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
```

Можно конечно прописывать полный путь к стилям, но я просто не понимаю почему пока у меня было два точно таких же контроллера, то все прекрасно работало. А как только добавил третий (который я пришел выше), то вылезла эта хрень со сменой директории.

Т.е. проблема появляется после того как в GetMapping появляется второй слеш: /people/
После этого браузер начинает все искать относительно пути /people
А предыдущие все контроллеры работали относительно основного пути /people или /show-people и т.д.

Comment: покажите как вы в шаблоне ссылаетесь на стили.

Comment: у вас относительный путь. он будет добавляться к текущему расположению. Соответственно, если вы находитесь на странице "/", будет запрос "/css/general.css", но на странице  "/admin/", стили уже будут искаться по адресу "/admin/css/genaral.css"...Просто используйте полный путь, который начинается с "/..." или с "http://", а вот относительные пути использовать не советую